# Changing MATLAB Plot tracker to a line

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, axes, markers

I have created a marker (just a "O" plot) that marks the value of a signal according to the time of a video.

[image: Here is the result of what I wrote:]

This is the code that updates the place of the marker with each iteration:

```
set(markerPlot,'XData',x(i*5), 'YData', v(i*5))
set(markerPlot_second, 'Xdata', x(i*5), 'YData', v_second(i*5));
```

However, I would like to turn these trackers into a one single vertical line. The line should move for example: with an iterator i as the code I wrote above but the o shape should be vertical line going from all the way up to down.

How can I plot a straight vertical line at different x values everytime? Also, is there an easier way to implement these kind of marker objects?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
set(markerPlot,'XData',[x(i*5), x(i*5)], 'YData', [0, 300])
```

You might need to replace `'YData', [0, 300]` if the range of your y-axis changes.